# Anchors not recognized in a circle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am surprised as to why there is no line drawn from `(a.center) -- (a.west)` with `\draw (a.center) -- (a.west);` in TikZ.

Are the anchors `north`, `south`, `east` and `west` not applicable to a `circle` in TikZ.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=5cm] node (a) {};
\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
\draw (a.center) -- (a.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your node is not in `circle` shape. Removing the center dot, add some text to the node

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=5cm] node (a) {abc};
%\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
\draw (a.center) -- (a.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

we can see that Ti*k*Z is still working well:

[image]

You drew a circle, but the node is still in `rectangle` shape.

Why don't you use a simpler way, which works?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=10cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
\draw (a.center) -- (a.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bonus:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=10cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm] node[right=1ex] {$O$};
\draw (a.center) -- (a.west) node[midway,above] {$R$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]